# How to get Latitude-Longitude Bounds in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

How to create Latitude-Longitude bounds in iPhone using two NE and SW latitude longitude coordinates and I want to check whether my current latitude longitude is in within my latitude longitude bound.

I created a bound using following latitude longitude coordinates:

```
double minLng = 7.880571
double maxLng = 8.357336
double minLat = 49.108775
double maxLat = 49.288638
```

I want to check my other latitude longitude is within this bound or not.

Comment: im ignorant of the problems.. but isnt it as simple as getting your current lat/long and see if they are in between the min and max for the lat and long respectively?

Comment: Yes I want to check my current location is in between my min & max lat-long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    if(newLocation.coordinate.latitude>=49.108775 && newLocation.coordinate.latitude<=49.288638 && newLocation.coordinate.longitude>=7.880571 && newLocation.coordinate.longitude<=8.357336 ) {

         // It is in the bounds

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by current you mean the device's current location, you need to look into the [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) class and its delegate methods, namely the `location` property which contains the information about current latitude and longitude. The rest is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I want to check my current location is within bound or not.I have already get current location.

Comment: Then just compare the location.coordinate.latitude and location.coordinate.longitude with your values, I don't see what is the actual issue here.